# Ubuntu 20.04 lost GUI on booting after update

Tags: 20.04, updates, gui

Ubuntu suggested to me to made updates and restarted the system. After that it never starts and the monitor gets stuck at this screen.

[image: some kind of report of something]

Nothing works except Ctr+Alt+F2 from where I am able to login to the system from the terminal.

I wonder if it is possible to make GUI work again without reinstalling Ubuntu? I learned from the internet that broken a system after updating/upgrading is not an uncommon occurence.

I tried:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

but it didn't help

I managed to start GRUB and run Ubuntu in recovery mode with a successful GUI startup, so I'm able to proceed with my work, but the normal boot process is still broken.

Lenovo W540, graphic card NVIDIA GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M]

Comment: First, apply any available updates with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade`. Then, run `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` in that virtual terminal, and reboot.

Comment: FYI:  I consider a *broken system after upgrade* an *extremely rare* and *unexpected* thing, and I'm sitting on a *development* release of Ubuntu (*even rarer on a stable or released system*).  I consider breakage like what you describe as usually being caused by user changes in the prior session BEFORE the reboot or upgrade; of which you gave no details  (*to be fair though; this is maybe the ~seventh such report I've seen after 1-Jan-2024; so your issue may in fact be valid & thus there is a legitimate bug*)

Comment: What models of computer  and graphics card do you have?

Comment: Maybe posting the output from `nvidia-smi` might provide clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the advice of @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I attempted to retrieve the output of nvidia-smi. However, instead of receiving expected data, I encountered an error:

```
> Command 'nvidia-smi' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt
> install nvidia-340               # version 340.108-0ubuntu5.20.04.2,
> or sudo apt install nvidia-utils-390         # version
> 390.157-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 sudo apt install nvidia-utils-450-server  # version 450.248.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470 
> # version 470.223.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470-server  # version 470.223.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 sudo
> apt install nvidia-utils-525         # version
> 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 sudo apt install nvidia-utils-525-server  # version 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 sudo apt install nvidia-utils-535         # version 535.129.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 sudo
> apt install nvidia-utils-535-server  # version
> 535.129.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 sudo apt install nvidia-utils-435         # version 435.21-0ubuntu7 sudo apt install nvidia-utils-440         # version 440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 sudo apt install
> nvidia-utils-418-server  # version 418.226.00-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
```

In an effort to resolve this, I tried installing various versions of the NVIDIA packages, specifically 470 and 390, but to no avail.

After several insightful sessions with chatGPT, I added a new PPA for graphics drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Subsequently, my attempt to install nvidia-utils-470 was successful, and I was able to restore the GUI session on system boot.

As a side effect of the installation, my DISPLAY system variable changed from :0 to :1. This required me to update my tools to ensure they continued to function correctly.

Comment: Good news indeed. Remember to accept your own answer in another day after system time delay expires.